# What is the difference between a mixed-design (split-plot) ANOVA and a linear mixed-effects model?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, linear, split-plot

My understanding is that in a mixed-design ANOVA, the between-subjects is the fixed effects factor and the within-subjects variable is the random effects factor. Not sure if that is any different from what is called the "linear mixed-effects model"?